# aChartEngine, How to get values from a chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm new developping applications for android, so I hope someone can help me.
I'm checking out a code from a friend, he made a class B to make the chart, in class A he created a GraphicalView and calls a GraphicalView method in class b to return the chart made. I want to get the value of the chart where the user clicks on, I've checked the demo of aChartEngine but in the example they create the setOnClickListener inside the code that creates the chart, so I want to know if someone know how can I get this values if the chart is already made in a GraphicalView, heare is an example of how it is.

```
class B{
    GraphicalView chart;
    public GraphicalView graf (){
        //heare is the code that generates the chart;
        return chart;
    }
}


class A{
    GraphicalView chartMade;
    b makeChart = new b();
    chartMade = makeChart.graf();
}
```

I want to get the values in class A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a vague so I cannot help you with specifics, but the basic approach is to override [GraphicalChart](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/GraphicalView.html)'s `onTouchEvent()` to call `getCurrentSeriesAndPoint()`. From this data you can call `getValue()` and / or `getXValue()` to get some of the chart's data.

---

**Addition**
Inside Class B try adding:

```
chartView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        SeriesSelection selection = ((GraphicalView) v).getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
        Log.v("Touch", selection.getValue() + ", " + selection.getXValue());
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: ok so I have to override onTouchEvent() over the GraphicalChart in order to call getCurrentSeriesAndPoint()?? but I can do that even if the chart is alredy made and I've got it in GraphicalView?? sorry I'm new at this